# Php echo not working with forms

Tags: php, html

I'm developing a website where people can vote on youtube videos.

In my toplist I have an upvote button. I generate it with php code, but on the first video it does not generate the form for the first button.

Here is the code:

```
echo "
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>$i</th>
        <td>$title</td>
        <td>$vote</td>
        <td>
        <a style='color: #00bcd4;' href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$url' target='_blank'>
          Watch
        </a>
      </td>
       <td>
         <form method='post' action='sendmusic.php'>
           <input value='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$url' type='hidden' name='url'>
           <input type='hidden' value='upvote' name='name'>
           <button type='submit' class='mdl-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored'>Upvote</button>
         </form>
       </td>
    </tr>

";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Echo a large block of text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672642/php-echo-a-large-block-of-text)

Comment: I think you're not showing all the relevant code as you are using $i which is most likely previously defined.

Comment: In the source does it show any of the form?

Comment: @Billy in the source at the first video it shows the whole code without the form, but after that it has the form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why wouldn't you just do:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++):
?> <!-- close php -->
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'><?php echo $i ?></th>
        <td><?php echo $title ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $vote ?></td>
        <td>
        <a style='color: #00bcd4;' href='<?php echo "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$url" ?>' target='_blank'>
          Watch
        </a>
      </td>
       <td>
         <form method='post' action='sendmusic.php'>
           <input value='<?php echo "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$url" ?>' type='hidden' name='url'>
           <input type='hidden' value='upvote' name='name'>
           <button type='submit' class='mdl-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored'>Upvote</button>
         </form>
       </td>
    </tr>
<!-- open php -->
<?php
endfor;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not write ot the form for the first time